# 'webkitIndexedDB' is deprecated. Please use 'indexedDB' instead

Tags: javascript

**下記警告が表示されるのですが、どういう意味でしょうか**
・「webkitStorageInfo」「webkitIndexedDB」を置換すれば良いのかな、と思いコード検索してみたのですが、見つかりません

> 'window.webkitStorageInfo' is deprecated. Please use
>   'navigator.webkitTemporaryStorage' or
>   'navigator.webkitPersistentStorage' instead.
>
> 'webkitIndexedDB' is deprecated. Please use 'indexedDB' instead.

---

[何かのテスト？](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26639415/webkitindexeddb-is-deprecated-please-use-indexeddb-instead)
・気にする必要はない？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

警告に書いてあるままの意味で、開いているページで使われている `webkitIndexedDB` を `indexedDB` に置き換えたりする必要があります。

拡張機能が使っていて警告が出る場合もあります。Chrome の DevTools で警告を見ている場合、警告の右側にどこで使われているかが表示されているので、拡張機能由来かどうかもそこで知ることができると思います。